# Inside DocuSign can we add checkboxes in the document at specific position using API?

Tags: docusignapi, docusignconnect, e-signature

We are sending the document from our app to DocuSign, and we want to add checkboxes at a specific position. How do we achieve this using API endpoint?

I tried adding checkbox manually on docusign portal now I want to check if can I achieve it by using API endpoint. I searched inside docusign API but didn't get any specific API for the same.

Answer (score 0):

xPosition and yPosituon properties on the object can be used to position any tab including checkbooks.

```
JSON:

checkboxTabs": [
  {
    "tabLabel" : "myCheckbox",
    "xPosition": "50",
    "yPosition": "50",
    "tabGroupLabels": [
      "checkboxgroup1"
    ],
  }
]
```

More information about checkbooks:
https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/tabs-deep-dive-checkboxes-and-radio-groups